# JavaScript load faster?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        var siteTitle = $.ajax({
          url: 'http/',
          type: 'POST',
          data: { http: 'siteTitle' },
          success: function(title) {
            $('.title').html(title);
          }
        });
</script>
```

I have a site title and it's grabbed through jQuery's $.ajax() call.  The title of the site needs to be configurable.  So I grab the title through the ajax request but it doesn't show up on the site for about ~1.5s.

Is there anyway to decrease this time?

The site title is in about 6 places so it looks awkward with nothing there for ~1.5s.

Thanks.

Comment: So what exactly takes those 1.5s to perform?

Comment: I have <span class="title"></span> 6 times on the page and it takes that amount of time to do.

Comment: What "it" takes 1.5s to execute?

Comment: The code written takes the title and puts it in any element with class="title"

Comment: You cant do much to decrease the time, it depends on the internet connection, server (backend) execution speed and few other factors. You have to optimize the server side code.

Comment: Keep Jquery file in your site , it will take less time other than calling from google .

Comment: @user3093095: what exactly takes that time? Have you checked how long the ajax request takes?

Comment: What @zerkms means is: Take a look at a modern browser's dev tools, like Chrome's. You can see there what exactly slows you down. Maybe it's fetching jQuery from a CDN and the ajax call is actually fast. What exactly takes 1.5 seconds.

Comment: And it's taking 1.5s to do.  Why is it so long..?

Comment: @CodingAnt: are you sure that OP can provide a better CDN than google?

Comment: Like what @ShaikMahaboobBasha said, you're using AJAX and fetching information so that you can display it. All of which occurs after the page has loaded. This is naturally going to take a second or two.

Comment: http://puu.sh/732jS.png It's taking 2.09s.  That seems awfully long and is horrible aesthetically.

Comment: @user3093095: provide a faster response then and require your user to buy a faster connection

Comment: You could use pure javascript which could fetch the title while all of the recourses are loaded and then set the title using jQuery. The idea being that the browser doesn't have to wait for jQuery to download before sending out the ajax request.

Comment: @Graham Walters: it's really a good chance jQuery is already in the user's cache. If it's not - it will be loaded just once

Comment: I don't think the Google CDN script is an issue. When the user first vists, sure. It will take a second to download, but after that it'll be cached and won't be a problem. (@zerkms beat me to it)

Comment: @user3093095 - You are using AJAX for the sites title. Just get the server to deliver the right content in the first place. Use AJAX for interactivity.

Comment: @user3093095 -  You download the jquery.min.js and save it your local project path and then refer the js to your HTML file. It will run faster and better.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend that you handle the configurable title on the server and render it with the page instead of requesting it through ajax.
Not sure what server side language you're using, but most will have a way to generate dynamic content on the server and pass it back to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Have some default text like "loading..." as your title value. Then it won't be so bad when the ajax call updates it 1-2 seconds later.

If it is a `span` element (instead of a window title) then maybe even a loading gif. I think users are getting used to seeing those spinners now and won't question the extra 1-2 seconds wait time for the actual title